# Creating and moving a Shape in Visual Studio C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, shapes

I am working on a little school project and I have to use Visual Studio C++/CLI with Windows Forms Application.

Since I am new to Windows Forms I am having some difficulties.

What I would like to achieve:

- Press a button
- A PictureBox will be created at starting position
- A timer will move the PictureBoxto some given position
- Pressing the button again will spawn a NEW PictureBox with a different name which will begin to move in the same direction as the first rectangle
- and so on.

Note: These pictureboxes have to have a different background color which must be randomly chosen out of 3 colors.

What I need to know is....

I know how to move a picturebox, but how do I dynamically create one with a custom name and color after a button press?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using Windows Forms with "C++", then it is C++/CLI and *not* standard C++.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, sorry I forgot to mention that it is C++/CLI

Comment: Use a `List<Rectangle>^`.  Draw them in the Paint event.  To move a rectangle, simply update the list with a new value.  And call Invalidate() so it will be repainted.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mention this is a school project, here is some high-level advice:

- You can draw on a form by either subscribing to the Paint event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or overriding the OnPaint method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.110).aspx).  Take a look at the Graphics object in the EventArgs.
- When the timer elapses, make adjustments to local variables (keeping track of the desired position of the Rectangle) and then call Invalidate() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(v=vs.110).aspx) to force the form to be redrawn.

I hope this helps you get pointed in the right direction.